# How can I use linq fetching data from sql?

Tags: json, reactjs

I am fetching MySQL table like this:

```
  class DanyPokoj extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state ={
          'items': [],
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.getItems();
    }

    getItems(){
      fetch('http://localhost:4000/room')
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(results => this.setState({'items': results})
      );
    }

    render() {
      return({
        this.state.items.map(function(item.index){
          console.log('My id:', item.id);
        }
     )}
  }
```

Everything works fine but I just need one column with ID = 1
Is there a possibility to use linq? I already tried with linq npm but acctually I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you only need one column? You mean that you only want the item with ID = 1?

Comment: Yes, exacly. Maybe I wrote that wrong

Comment: To get the item with ID = 1 you write:
this.state.items.find(item => item.ID === 1)

Comment: Oh it works but when I have 2 items in my SQL its doing it 2 times, if 5 items then 5 times. Can I change that so it will it do just once?